# Can Amazon actually read my code stored at AWS?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, openstack

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I'm developing a web application, and I suggested using AWS. Nevertheless, my bosses are concerned about Amazon being able to read/steal our code. I don't know why Amazon would want to get my code, but it's not me the one which is worried about that.

I guess there should be some kind of encryption, or at least a legal clause at the AWS user contract where it says that Amazon won't do that or you will be able to sue them. The thing is I haven't been able to find this information so far.

Does anyone know where to find this information? I really want them to let me use AWS, since I think it is a great opportunity to learn about this technology.

Bonus: I know there are similar services, such as Heroku, or Openstack. I will also accept the kind of information resource I'm searching for any other similar services. But unless anyone can point that AWS is not the best option out there, I'd rather stick to AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) You should assume they can read your code B) you should also assume they don't care about your code.

Edit: Possibly more useful resources w/regards to AWS security

> http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1697
>
> http://aws.amazon.com/compliance/

Comment: I agree with B, but most enterprise bosses won't. I really doubt that statement A is true, are you absolutely sure about that?

Comment: There is no possible way that couldn't if they really wanted to. Have you ever been able to design a system where your customers could put stuff into it but you couldn't get at it if you really wanted to? you pretty much need to assume that someone, somewhere can. The NSA has the capability to intercept and access whatever they want, do you really think AWS couldn't if they wanted to? I doubt the average AWS employee has the ability to simply go browsing thru random  data, but I have no doubt that AWS has the capability if they needed or wanted to, whether or not they would publicly admit it.

Comment: and quite frankly, I suspect you would have more risk from a determined hacker outside of AWS getting thru security holes that you yourself has left open, rather than via a backdoor that AWS may have. Not trivializing your concern, I had some of the same, but reality is reality.

Comment: As I said before, I agree with you at 100%, but I would need at least some clause written by Amazon where they say they won't, even if they are capable. If I can't find that, I won't be able to convince my bosses.